# Updating a jQuery flexbox

Tags: jquery, jquery-flexbox

Is there a way to update the results of a jQuery flexbox with a JSON array? I have already created the flexbox, and I want to update its results.

I initialize my flexbox as follows:

```
$('#myFlex').flexbox({  
        "results": [  
            { "id": "1", "name": "Ant" },  
            { "id": "2", "name": "Bear" }
        ]}, 
    {  
    allowInput: false,  
    paging: false,  
    maxVisibleRows: 8  
});
```

This is [taken from the documentation](http://www.fairwaytech.com/flexbox/flexbox-demos.aspx#demo10), and it works.  Suppose I want to update the elements without reinitializing the flexbox.  How can this be done?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Ok, so I hacked myself a solution!

Flexbox sets the data through the variable `o.source` upon initialization.

What I did was store (and access) `o.source` as jQuery `.data()`.  This allows me to view/change the value.

Answer (score 1):

While experimenting with this same problem, I found out that jQuery Flexbox stores the data passed as a reference. This means that you can do this:

```
var data = {results: [{id:1,name:'Ant'},{id:2,name:'Bear'}], total:2};
$('#myFlex').flexbox(data);

// ...

data.results[data.total] = {id:3,name:'Cat'};
data.total++;
```

with the stock plugin and it will work. The only thing to keep in mind is that you must remember to also update the `.total` property when adding new elements.

Answer (score 0):

You've not specified how you've initialized flexbox or how you're getting the data back. However, according to the [documentation](http://www.fairwaytech.com/flexbox.aspx) and the [demos](http://www.fairwaytech.com/flexbox/flexbox-demos.aspx#demo2), the JSON property named `results` is used to get the rows of data when you've specified a URL. This should all happen automatically. For example (straight from the docs):

```
$.ready(function() {  
    // results.aspx is the page that returns json data in the expected format  
    $('#fb').flexbox('results.aspx');   
});
```

Sample response:

```
{"results":[  
    {"id":1,"name":"Ant"},   
    {"id":2,"name":"Bear"},  
    {...} // more results here...  
]}
```

Alternatively, you should be able to use `resultsProperty` to specify a different property name.

Comment: "you should be able to use resultsProperty to specify a different property name." How can I do this?  $("#myid").results(results) doesnt work (resultsProperty == 'results')

Comment: @babonk Can you post 1. How you're initializing flexbox and 2. What your response looks like? This should all be happening automatically.

Comment: Updated the question, tell me if there's any more details you want and I can add them

Comment: @babonk Ah, I see - you're using the static option. AFAICT, that data cannot be updated. The only way to allow for updating is to use a URL which should point to a server-side resource which responds with the JSON data.

Comment: I guess I'm going to try delve into the plugin myself.. Will post my answer when done